# Email Notifications in sandbox don't show product details?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I specified all the payment details like `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME` in the PayPal Express Checkout and it shows fine in the checkout page, but when I check the PayPal Sandbox email notifications, it shows like this:

```
Apr 4, 2015 14:14:05 PDT | Transaction ID: XXXXXXXXXX

Hello Check Out's Test Store,

You received a payment of $100.55 USD from test buyer (test-buyer@domain.com)

Thanks for using PayPal. You can now ship any items. To see all the transaction details, log in to your PayPal account.

It may take a few moments for this transaction to appear in your account.

Seller Protection - Eligible


----------------------------------------------------------------

Buyer:
test buyer
test-buyer@domain.com


Confirmed shipping address
test buyer
1 Main St
San Jose, CA 95131
United States

Instructions to merchant:
The buyer hasn't entered any instructions.

Shipping details:
You haven’t added any shipping details.
-----------------------------------
Purchase Details
-----------------------------------
Description:
Unit price: $100.55 USD
Qty: 1
Amount: $100.55 USD

Subtotal: $100.55 USD
Total: $100.55 USD

Payment: $100.55 USD
Payment sent to: email@domain.com




----------------------------------------------------------------



Questions? Go to the Help Center at: www.paypal.com/help.

Please do not reply to this email. This mailbox is not monitored and you will not receive a response. For assistance, log in to your PayPal account and click Help in the top right corner of any PayPal page.

To receive email notifications in plain text instead of HTML, log in to your PayPal account and go to your Profile to update your settings.
```

It should be 3 products, which show fine on the checkout page ...but not in the notification email. What's wrong?

Comment: DId you pass all the line item details in the DoExpress Checkout API call too ? Can you paste the transaction id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are passing the line item details in the DO EXpress Checkout API call as well otherwise you won't see the details on email as well as on transaction details page . Below is the sample email once you pass the line item details in both API calls.

```
 Apr 4, 2015 15:11:38 PDT | Transaction ID: 4AL60542MT258063W

Hello Eshan New BBUSINESS,

You received a payment of $105.87 USD from Eshan Personal Test Account (XXXXXXXXXXXX)

Thanks for using PayPal. You can now ship any items. To see all the transaction details, log in to your PayPal account.

It may take a few moments for this transaction to appear in your account.

Seller Protection - Eligible


----------------------------------------------------------------

Buyer:
Eshan Personal Test Account
XXXXXXXXXXX
408-767-7151

Confirmed shipping address
Eshan Personal Test Account
cxas
asa
FL, FL 95616
United States

Instructions to merchant:
The buyer hasn't entered any instructions.

Shipping details:
You haven’t added any shipping details.
-----------------------------------
Purchase Details
-----------------------------------
Description:10
ecaf Kona Blend Coffee, Item#:623083
Unit price:$9.95 USD
Qty:2
Amount:$19.90 USD
Description:Coffee Filter bags, Item#:623084
Unit price:$39.70 USD
Qty:2
Amount:$79.40 USD

Subtotal: $99.30 USD
Shipping and handling: $5.99 USD
Insurance: $1.00 USD
Tax: $2.58 USD
Total: $105.87 USD

Payment: $105.87 USD
Payment sent to: XXXXXXXXXXXXX




----------------------------------------------------------------



Questions? Go to the Help Center at: www.paypal.com/help.

Please do not reply to this email. This mailbox is not monitored and you will not receive a response. For assistance, log in to your PayPal account and click Help in the top right corner of any PayPal page.

To receive email notifications in plain text instead of HTML, log in to your PayPal account and go to your Profile to update your settings.

PPID PP341 - b48608ec2a27a
```